# How do I process for building workitems ready for build using TFSBuild?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nant, tfsbuild

I'm doing research on the proper way to output a list of work items/changesets included in a build. In my current NAnt scripted daily build process I have a target which creates a list of tickets or work items and changesets that were deemed "Ready for build" based on a TFS Query. What would be the proper way of handling this using TFSBuild?

Comment: The _proper_ way does not include a NAnt script in the build process.

Comment: If you have TFS, then you have TFSBuild.. why would you use a nant script at all?

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating our build process from using NAnt to TFSBuild. Right now we run a TFS query to get all the work items and changesets associated with those work items. I'm trying to determine how to do that in TFSBuild so that I can send a email report out to developers, testers, and management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the workitems and changesets associated while doing check-in to the source control. When build gets completed, In build summary window you will find  the list of workitems and changesets included in build.

Comment: Thanks. Related to this question. Is there a way to capture that information inherently or would I have to write some sort of custom activity to capture and email that info?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to write custom activity to view it but would require one to email the information.